# OAuth failing for flask-dance with Azure AD

Tags: flask, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, lodash, flask-dance

Im trying to implement OAuth authentication for an example dash app running on flask.
App is registered in Azure AD, but when trying to authenticate with the flask-dance library,im getting this error:

Error AADSTS70001 - Application with Identifier None was not found in the directory

```
from dash import Dash, html
from werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix import ProxyFix
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for
from flask_dance.contrib.azure import azure, make_azure_blueprint
import os


CLIENT_ID = os.environ.get("CLIENT_ID")
CLIENT_SECRET = os.environ.get("CLIENT_SECRET")


def login_required(func):
    """Require a login for the given view function."""

    def check_authorization(*args, **kwargs):
        if not azure.authorized or azure.token.get("expires_in") < 0:
            return redirect(url_for("azure.login"))
        else:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return check_authorization

blueprint = make_azure_blueprint(
    client_id=CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
    tenant="MyTenant", # Hidden for this example
    scope=["user.read"],
)


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "secretkey123"
app.register_blueprint(blueprint, url_prefix="/login")

# dash_app = create_app(server=app)
dash_app = Dash(__name__, server=app)

# use this in your production environment since you will otherwise run into problems
# https://flask-dance.readthedocs.io/en/v0.9.0/proxies.html#proxies-and-https
app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app, x_proto=1, x_host=1)

for view_func in app.view_functions:
    if not view_func.startswith("azure"):
        app.view_functions[view_func] = login_required(app.view_functions[view_func])

dash_app.layout = html.Div(children=[
  html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),
  html.Div(children="You are logged in!")
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dash_app.run_server(debug=True, port=5010, host="localhost")
```

Comment: Bit of a guess, but the error reads like you're not getting the values from your environment variables. Are you sure you've set your ClientID and Secret in the environment variables correctly? As a sanity check try (temporarily) hard-code them in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the scope. it was not necessary and when it was removed, the rest worked just fine